# Equation in Free Group

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let $F$ be a free group and $a \in F$. Assume that for any natural $n>1$ the equation $x^n=a$ has solutions (that is, $a$ is infinitely divisible). Show that $a=1$.

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: The question is valid. Also check out http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90441/non-abelian-divisible-groups

Comment: Thanks for support. I was surprised when I found it "On Hold". After I saw the mathstack activity done by those people (who put it on hold), I was happy that it was not done by serious people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, $a$ may be supposed cyclically reduced. If $x^n=a$, then $x$ is cyclically reduced, hence $\ell g(x^n)=n \cdot \ell g(x)$, where $\ell g( \cdot)$ is the length function on a free basis. So $n \ell g(x)= \ell g (a)$ for all $n \geq 1$, hence $\ell g(a)=0$ ie. $a=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof that uses a basic property of free groups: any element $\ne e$ maps to by a morphism to a $\it{finite}$ group onto an element  $\ne e$. The reason for it is this: there do not exists non-trivial universal equalities valid in any finite group.

Take an element $a\ne e$ and map it to a finite group of cardinality $n$ to an element $\ne e$. It's clear that the equation $x^n = a$ cannot have any solution in $F$.

Comment: Your reason should be "...there do not exists non-trivial universal equalities valid in any finite group *with a fixed number of generators*", no?

Comment: Yes: no non-trivial universal equalities involving finitely many elements.  However, there do exist non-trivial $\it{implications}$ valid only for finite groups of the form : if $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n) =e$ then $Q(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = e$,  since there are non-hopfian groups.